# ¿Como ocultar un submenu desplegable reponsive al darle clic de nuevo?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estoy creando una pagina web básico, el cual me han salido detalles conforme voy avanzando el cual la quiero dejar bien, en modo escritorio no tengo problemas, y ahora estoy adaptándolo para dispositivos móviles es ahí donde me a sacado poco dolores de cabeza, bueno la cuestión es con el submenu desplegable al dar clic si me hace la acción de desplegar pero al momento de darle clic ya no se me oculta, cuando pongo a inspeccionar desactivo el táctil y paso por encima si funciona bien porque esta como en modo escritorio y activo de nuevo el táctil y ya no funciona, no se hay que configurar los navegadores para lo del táctil.

```js
function cerrar() {
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link:not(.servic)'); 
    const menuToggle = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent'); 
    const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle: false}); 
    navLinks.forEach( function(l) { l.addEventListener('click', function() 
    {  if (menuToggle.classList.contains('show')) { bsCollapse.toggle(); } }) ; });
    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

/* NAVBAR*/
.dropdown-menu{
  border: 0;
  text-align: left !important;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}


.nav-item{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
  margin-right: 30px; 
}
.dropdown-item{
  color: rgb(247, 250, 250);;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}


#informacion{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion" onclick="cerrar()">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#producto" onclick="cerrar()">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle servic" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="" aria-expanded="false"href="#servicios" >Servicios</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">VENTAS</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">TRANSPORTE</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">MAYOREO</a></li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<!-- DATOS DE INFORMACIÓN -->

    <section id="informacion">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>
      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
        
        Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
        <br>
        ¿Por qué lo usamos?
        
        Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
         </p>
     </div> 
    </section>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="js/cerrar.js"> </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu principal problema es que tienes `data-bs-toggle=""` cuando debería ser `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`, luego has puesto un efecto hover sobre el submenú que interfiere con bootstrap (`.navbar-nav li:hover > ul`) tienes que borrar eso, y hay un margen que sobra `margin-right: 30px;` que colocará el submenú en una posición no deseada

```js
function cerrar() {
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link:not(.servic)'); 
    const menuToggle = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent'); 
    const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle: false}); 
    navLinks.forEach( function(l) { l.addEventListener('click', function() 
    {  if (menuToggle.classList.contains('show')) { bsCollapse.toggle(); } }) ; });
    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

/* NAVBAR*/
.dropdown-menu{
  border: 0;
  text-align: left !important;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
}




.nav-item{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 


}
.dropdown-item{
  color: rgb(247, 250, 250);;
  font-size: 14px;
 
  
}


#informacion{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion" onclick="cerrar()">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#producto" onclick="cerrar()">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle servic" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Servicios</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">VENTAS</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">TRANSPORTE</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">MAYOREO</a></li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<!-- DATOS DE INFORMACIÓN -->

    <section id="informacion">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>
      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
        
        Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
        <br>
        ¿Por qué lo usamos?
        
        Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
         </p>
     </div> 
    </section>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="js/cerrar.js"> </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que tal amigo, anteriormente ya lo tenia así, pero quite el dropdown, porque en modo escritorio al dar clic al elemento submenu que es desplegable se abre pero si quito el cursor no se oculta y tengo que darle de nuevo clic al elemento para que se oculte, por eso decide poner el efecto hover, pero en responsivo no va eso.

Comment: @Miguel Es que así funcionan los dropdown, debes clickear en algún lado para cerrarlo. Y en mi opinión es la mejor manera, no hay nada más molesto que los menú que se cierran solos, y tener que perseguirlos para que no se cierren. además como haces un `hover` en una pantalla `touch`?

Comment: Si tendré que dejarlo con el `dropdown` ya que el efecto `hover` no existe para el touch gracias de todos modos.